# How to make sure user inputs a value?

Tags: c

I am trying to get this code to verify that the user input a value. It works if i use gets() but when I change it to fgets() it stops working. I want it to keep looping until the user enters a string of at least 1  character but less than 25 I am new to programming if it isn't apparent in my code. Thanks!

```
int main(void)
{
    char input[25], inputNew[25];
    int i;
    int x;
    int y;
    do
    {
        printf("Please enter a string less then 25 characters!\n");
        fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);  
        y = strlen(input);  
    }
    while(y>25 || y<=0);

    for (i = 0; i <= strlen(input); i++)
    {
        inputNew[i] = toupper(input[i]);
        for (x = 1; x <= strlen(input); x+=2)
        {
        inputNew[x] = tolower(input[x]);
        }
    }
    printf("The new value is: %s.\n", inputNew);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could use `getline` and have your `input` be a `malloc`-ed pointer.

Comment: ...if you're willing to go glibc-only.

Comment: change your variable size for char input[25] to something greater than 25. check this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/12907742/937420)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fgets` keeps the ending newline, whereas `gets` throws it out.

Therefore, you'll have to change your check to `y <= 1` if you use `fgets`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, avoid `gets()` in *any* serious code. `gets()` is ill-designed and not safe. Never use it.

Second. `fgets()` keeps the newline at the end of the buffer (while `gets()` discards it).

Third, `y <= 0` is probably wrong in the case of `fgets()`, since it will likely read at least one character (the newline). You should replace it with `y < 2`.

Last, and *most* important: ***please indent your code.*** :)

Answer (score 0):

nneonneo beat me to the answer:

> The gets() function is equivalent to fgets() with an infinite size and
>   a
>        stream of stdin, except that the newline character (if any) is not stored
>        in the string.

From http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fgets/

I just added the references...

Answer (score 0):

you have declared the variable input with a static size 25 . So i don't see a chance of it getting a larger size for y = strlen(input);

Change your

```
char input[25];
```

to

```
char input[100];
```

anything more than 25.